# how to check whether the comma-separated value in the database is present in JSON data or not using python

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x, csv

I just have to check the JSON data on the basis of comma-separated e_code in the table.
how to filter only that data where users e_codes are available
in the database:

```
id         email          age      e_codes
1.         abc@gmail       19     123456,234567,345678
2.         xyz@gmail       31     234567,345678,456789
```

This is my JSON data

```
[
  {
    "ct": 1,
    "e_code": 123456,
  },
  {
    "ct": 2,
    "e_code": 234567,
  },
{
    "ct": 3,
    "e_code": 345678,
},
{
    "ct": 4,
    "e_code": 456789,
  },
{
    "ct": 5,
    "e_code": 456710,
  }
]
```

Comment: You'll want to import both the CSV data and the JSON data then compare them.  What have you tried so far?  Do you have any code?

Comment: Yes, sir, I have loaded the JSON file, and also fetch the database using cursor.fetchall. also, i have to send the filtered data to the respective email id

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code so we can see what you are having difficulty with?

Comment: yes, @Axe319 wait

Answer (score 1):

If efficiency is not an issue, you could loop through the table, split the values to a list by using `case['e_codes'].split(',')` and then, for each code loop through the JSON to see whether it is present.
This might be a little inefficient if your data, JSON, or number of values are long.

It might be better to first create a lookup dictionary in which the codes are the keys:

```
lookup={}
for e in my_json:
    lookup[e['e_code']] = 1
```

You can then check how many of the codes in your table are actually in the JSON:

```
## Let's assume that the "e_codes" cell of the 
## current line is data['e_codes'][i], where i is the line number

for i in lines:
    match = [0,0]
    for code in data['e_codes'][i].split(','):
        try:
            match[0]+=lookup[code]
            match[1]+=1
        except:
            match[1]+=1

    if match[1]>0: share_present=match[0]/match[1]
```

For each case, you get a `share_present`, which is 1.0 if all codes appear in the JSON, 0.0 if none of them do and some value between to indicate the share of codes that were present. Depending on your threshold for keeping a case you can set a filter to `True` or `False` depending on this value.

Comment: thank you so much, Martin Wettstein I will check and let you know,